# EXPO React-Native: expo-sqlite compile error on TVOS 17.0

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, tvos, expo-sqlite

I'm trying to work with database SQL Lite on react native using SQL lite data base and expo library expo-sqlite.

- The package is well installed with **npx expo install expo-sqlite**
- I have already removed node_modules, package-lock.json, pods, Bulds (from IOS folder)
- Reinstalled with **npm i**
- Reinstalled pods with **pod install**
- Followed a tutorial on https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/

But I have an error *"Error: Cannot find native module 'ExpoSQLite', js engine: hermes"*

So when showing app, the results is ERROR screen on emulator:

[image]

I have found the line where module is called but as I do understand, expo do not complies required files.

const ExpoSQLite = requireNativeModule('ExpoSQLite'); from **SQLite.ts** of node_modules/expo-sqlite

When comment a line of calls to a database, the error is gone and code is shown but there is no DB attached.

Strange but there is no same error when compile with Android version

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

Andrew